# In Magento 2 the UPS integration stopped working. Did the gateway url change?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.3

This is the full error code:

```
[2023-05-24 18:16:52] main.DEBUG: array (
  'request' =>
  array (
    'accept_UPS_license_agreement' => 'yes',
    '10_action' => '4',
    '13_product' => 'GNDRES',
    '14_origCountry' => 'US',
    '15_origPostal' => 'EDITED',
    'origCity' => 'EDITED',
    '19_destPostal' => 'EDITED',
    '22_destCountry' => 'US',
    '23_weight' => 2.0,
    '47_rate_chart' => 'Customer Counter',
    '48_container' => '00',
    '49_residential' => '01',
    'weight_std' => 'lbs',
  ),
  'result' => '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.ups.com/error.page">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
',
) [] []
```

This is the gateway url I'm currently using:
https://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi

The Magento version is `2.4.3` and the error started happening yesterday and still persists.

Has the gateway url change? Is there some other problem with the integration? Thank you!

Comment: Yes same issue faced in last night.

Answer (score 1):

From UPS: "The Quick Cost Calculator Data Stream (QCC DS) Rating Tool on ups.com (URL= http://www.ups.com/using/services/rave/qcostcgi.cgi   has been completely sunset. This tool was in place prior to the Calculate Time and Cost (CTC) tool which was place into production in 2012.

Customers that are still using the QCC DS tool may call explaining that they are not able to access the Quoting tool to get a rate.

If you are still using QCC DS, we suggest that you switch to the UPS Developers Kit Rating API.  As the new Quote and CTC apps have a UI, but QCC DS does not so going to the Rating API would be a smoother transition for the customer.

Another option is to request a Sales Resource to contact them to provide other shipping options. "

Our resolution:
Switching the "UPS Type" to "United Parcel Service XML" in Admin > Stores > Configuration > Sales > Delivery Methods

We had to do a combination of switching to UPS XML as well as "Revalidate Your Access Key". In UPS account https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit > Manage Access Keys > Revalidate Your Access Key. This needs to be done on an annual basis now.

Comment: If you ship UPS using a discount consolidator (which thousands of ecom shippers are) and don't have or need a UPS account, any idea on a replacement url we can plug into M2?  

UPS has alienated so  many shippers and removed themselves as a shipping option from a lot of sites by sun-setting this url.

Answer (score 1):

I just talked with the UPS and they mentioned that there was a change on the API for small business.

The customer classification need to be 00 now.

I am not sure what this is but can one help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So UPS has eliminated AKA "Sunset" the simple url link that was being used by many to conduct business. I contacted them via email because you can't talk to anyone that will reason with you regarding this. No response back via email. You can't use the XML version without a access key-I was told by an unreasonable person at UPS that they are not issuing them. What to do? Here is what we did to over come the situation. We setup regional flat rate shipping costs per product by using the Customizable Options feature. We feature 21 products-had to do it for each one as the shipping cost varies by product and region. We made it a requirement of the product with an Option - TBD = To Be Determined and a email to obtain a quote, yes more work for us but at least were back in business with a way consumers can once again order from or site. I am taking the time to write this to help others overcome the situation. If you have a large quantity of products this may not be an easy but rather a tedious task to achieve.